# Regex to strip all directorynames from Path (leave filename)

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to remove all directorynames from a path:

```
Payload/brownie.app/Info.plist
```

should become

```
Info.plist
```

What regex should I use or can I use replace() from String in java?
thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try with this:

```
new File("Payload/brownie.app/Info.plist").getName()
```

This returns the filename without directories.

Example:

```
String filename = new File("Payload/brownie.app/Info.plist").getName();
System.out.println(filename);
```

Outupt:

```
Info.plist
```

Comment: not Regex but the best (object oriented, readability) solution IMO: +1

Comment: I agree with you, @Carlos Heuberger ;)

Comment: Be careful using `File.getName()` to strip paths if the path you're working with may have come from another operating system (such as a Linux webserver parsing a DOS path of an uploaded file). `File.getName()` only strips whatever the operating system considers to be directories. "C:\somedir\myfile.txt" is a perfectly valid filename on Linux.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need a regex. Just find the last slash and use substring:

```
int index = path.lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar);
String name = path.substring(index+1);
```

or use:

```
new File(path).getName();
```

Comment: problem with this solution is that you can have urls like this: .../somepage.html?rurl=/x/y/z/something.html

Comment: Also, make sure to check for the extreme cases, like the file being in the root folder or the path being null.
<code>
    if (path == null) return null;
    int index = path.lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar);
    String name = path.substring(index+1);
    return index == -1 ? null : path.substring( 0, index );

Comment: Won't work if filename ends with a slash. Won't work if filename doesn't doesn't have a path ( relative file ) and is just a filename. Won't work for directory name just "slash" for root directory. Won't work for backward slashes, and mixed slashed paths ( windows ) coming from other systems.

Answer (score 9):

This covers all spectrums directories, trailing or starting slashes.

All others here so far does not...

```
public static String extractFilename(String path)  {  
    java.util.regex.Pattern p       = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile('^[/\\\\]?(?:.+[/\\\\]+?)?(.+?)[/\\\\]?$');
    java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = p.matcher(path);

    if ( matcher.find() ) {
        return matcher.group(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Used:

```
println extractFilename("data\\\\path/to/file/RandomFile.pdf")
println extractFilename("RandomFile.pdf")
println extractFilename("RandomFile.pdf/")
println extractFilename("data\\\\path/to/file/RandomFile.pdf/")
println extractFilename("/data\\\\path/to/file/RandomFile.pdf/")
println extractFilename("/data\\\\path/to/file/RandomFile.pdf")
println extractFilename("/RandomFile.pdf")
println extractFilename("/RandomFile.pdf/")
println extractFilename("/")
```

Prints

```
RandomFile.pdf
RandomFile.pdf
RandomFile.pdf
RandomFile.pdf
RandomFile.pdf
RandomFile.pdf
RandomFile.pdf
RandomFile.pdf
/
```

.......................................................................EDIT............................................................................

**Explanation for Uday. It was actually pretty complicated one, and I am not sure I can argue for all of it today, but I will give it a try :)**

```
^[/\\\\]?(?:.+[/\\\\]+?)?(.+?)[/\\\\]?$
```

0: Entire regex

```
^
```

1: Starts with

```
[/\\\\]?
```

2: A forward slash or backward slash ( yes, four slashes for one, crazy! ). Once or not at all, so not required.

```
(?:.+[/\\\\]+?)?
```

3: This step is the complicated one. It is intended to skip everything but the last one that matches this exact pattern, a non capturing group (?:... were we are looking for any character several times, followed by one slash.

The group can be repeated many times, but it is non greedy. So it is saying do this, except until you match the following regex explained in 4.

This entire piece though, is not required, because of the ? outside the parentheses. For instance, "/RandomFile.pdf/" will not generate a match here, and continue with 4.

However, now I do find this a bit weird, since .+ is greedy, still it is looking forward to the slash for the match. It might be the nature of groups, that they are non-greedy or a bug in Java pattern syntax.

```
(.+?)[/\\\\]?$
```

4: Since the regex applies for all of the string, it also has to match up to the end. The previous match at 3 was non greedy, reluctant using +?, meaning it will only match as long as the regex after it doesn't also match. Our word is at the end $ is within the parentheses which may or may not end with a slash. I have chosen to return the root path as the file name if there is no filename, but just a slash, since it is also a filename ( directory name )

5: The parentheses is a capturing group, which is what we return at the end.

I hope this clarifies a bit.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I had a path which had BOTH / and \ (got it from some compiler for ARM). This regex worked perfectly. Can you please write down the explanation for the regex. Java regex confuses me a lot.

Comment: I added an explanation uday ;)

Comment: This was the only one which worked for me. I am developing on windows but running service on Linux and users uploads files from Windows using Internet Explorer. In this case I will have file names with backslashes. codelahoma's comment helped me to focusing on this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use replace with regex,  `String name = directory.replaceAll(".*/","")`, simple as that.

Comment: Won't work if filename ends with a slash. Won't work if filename doesn't doesn't have a path ( relative file ). Won't work for directory name just "slash" for root directory. Won't work for backward slashes, and mixed slashed paths ( windows ).

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are all simpler than using a full-blown regular expression. If you really want to use one, though, here's a regex pattern you could use: **".*/(.+)"**

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*/(.+)");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher("Payload/brownie.app/Info.plist");

    if ( matcher.find() ) {
        System.out.println("result: "+matcher.group(1));
    }
```

As you can see from the other answers, this is more code than is strictly needed, but if you are doing more sophisticated pattern matching and string extraction then regular expressions are a good way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with a file path that's been passed by a browser to a web server, you can't be sure if it'll be a DOS style path, Unix style, or just a filename without path. If you really want a RegEx, this should do it:

```
String path = "Payload/brownie.app/Info.plist";
String filename = path.replaceFirst("(^.*[/\\\\])?([^/\\\\]*)$","$2");
```

This will work whether there's a DOS, Unix, or absent path.

It'd be more legible, though, to use substrings as [dogbane suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838730/regex-to-strip-all-directorynames-from-path-leave-filename/4838751#4838751), but adding logic to check for both types of file separator (again, only if you're dealing with multi-platform input).

Comment: Better yet, just use [Johan's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838730/regex-to-strip-all-directorynames-from-path-leave-filename/4838749#4838749) much simpler regex (which I somehow overlooked), but add backslash in there like so: `".*[/\\\\]"`